# what are the reasons to have a waiting time before redirecting a page?

Tags: url, redirect, web

Quite some pages around the web have a waiting time period before redirecting you to the "correct" url.

Sometimes, they are downloading pages that make you wait a few seconds before the download starts, other times, they are simple redirects for when urls have changed for whatever reason, etc.

In most cases they also provide a direct link to the destination url, and mention "if your page doesn't reload automatically, click this link" (or something like that).

My question is, What is the reason of waiting? Why not to simply redirect immediately? what are the "benefits" of waiting?

The only reason i can think of is when the page has moved, and you notify the user so they, for instance, may change they bookmarks or something.

But in most other cases, the user just don't want to wait and doesn't care. So if they already provide the direct link anyway, (so the user can click it ASAP), why not to simply redirect immediately, and make it 'transparent' to the user?

So what are the real reasons to wait for redirects? and in which cases they apply?

Comment: I could immagine to prevent from exxessive access to get servers down

Comment: It may not be an *intentional* wait; maybe something's gone awry with the original request, an error happened but that error doesn't get propagated to the UI. Maybe some additional work is happening. Maybe it's just how long it takes. It could be different in different cases :)

Answer (score 0):

If there's a noticeable delay, it usually means that JavaScript is being used.

As far as I know, there isn't any actual use for it.  One difference however, is how search engines handle it.  If it returns a 200 (OK) status code, the search engines may index it, if it has suitable content.  HTTP redirects are never indexed (just their destinations).

For temporary flexible redirects (like I'm feeling lucky) the server should issue a [302 response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2).

If it's moved permanently, the server should respond with 301.  This code also means that the browser should cache the redirection indefinitely, which works like updating a bookmark.

Comment: And whats about the HTML redirect delay?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you mean HTTP redirects, and what about them?